# How HTML5 Boilerplate converts github wiki to its website?

Tags: github, wiki

HTML5 Boilerplate has [Doc page](http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/) which integrated with github wiki.

How did they convert github wiki to normal html site?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

github supports git access to the Wiki content, stored in markdown format. ([Example](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/wiki/_access))

This can then be converted to HTML using [this script](https://github.com/mklabs/h5bp-docs/blob/master/lib/h5bp.js).

In addition, commit hooks can be set up, such that whenever the wiki is modified, the new version is automatically fetched.